# How to handle Microsoft strange command line handling of escape character

Tags: c++, escaping, command-line-arguments

A third party system calls a program I am writing that takes in a path as the first argument on the command line.  An example command line might be something like:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX"

Actually this isn't printed how I want in this editor, an example input might be:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX\"`

The problem is that Windows seems to correctly identify the first and second backslash as backslash characters and not the escape character.  But the third backslash is seen as an escape of " and so you end up argv[1] being:

C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX"

Is this a bug?  What is a reliable way to handle this issue?

Sample code below.

If you run the program: test.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX"

it prints:

```
>test.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX\"
No. args: 2
arg[0] = test.exe
arg[1] = C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX"
path: C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX" does not exist


/*
  pass in for example

  test.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\ProgramX\"

  prints path does not exist
*/
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>

bool DirectoryExists(const char* path)
{
    DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(path);

    return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES &&
        (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    std::cout << "No. args: " << argc << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        std::cout << "arg[" << i << "] = " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }

    if (argc > 1) {
        std::string path(argv[1]);

        std::cout << "path: " << path << (DirectoryExists(path.c_str()) ? " exists" : " does not exist") << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=vs-2019 - `A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash, \", is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark (").` documented behavior. so, technically not a bug.

Comment: Possible workarounds: Use `/` character; change program to not require that trailing backslash (since requiring it is not typical behavior); try `\ProgramX"\` (putting the backslash outside of the quoted block; rewrite command line parsing (advanced users).